# no data received from in AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I test my first AJAX form, but when I submit my form the alert message just shows '2'. I search for sending ajax data to the same page and I found, that I can do that, but URL is optional.

my PHP code:

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["name"]))
    {
    $data="test string";
    echo json_encode($data);
    }



?>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
$.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'index.php', 
            data        : $(this).serialize(), 
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true

        })

    .done(function(data) {
    alert(1);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        alert(2);
            });
            event.preventDefault();

});


});
```

I don't know where I go wrong?

Comment: After `echo json_encode($data);` execution of page continues and `<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>....` added to your string. So it's not a json anymore.

Comment: If you're just posting the value to the index.php again, you don't need ajax. Ajax is for async post, i.e. staying on the same page and sending data to another php-script under water, without it interupting the page you're on. Just remove the ajax script, see what happens

Comment: @u_mulder this means that all of my code append to data string??

Comment: @myfunkyside I wanna show an error or success message at current page for this reason I force to use ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to delegate page generation and json-response generation to different pages. At least you should isolate it, because the following part of page also ends up in ajax-response:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input name="name" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    ...
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Modifiyng your script, you can do something like that:

```
<? 
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
  // And don't forget to specify content type!
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  $data="test string";
  echo json_encode($data);
} else { 
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input name="name" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<? } ?>
```

And, for future, please, post the exact request and response information in your questions, which you can get on Network page for developer tools of chrome, for example.